# How to update certificate on AWS APIGateway custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I don't see a way to update the certificate on the AWS APIGateway custom domain. If I create a new custom domain with a new cert, I can't use the existing *.cloudfront.net domain. I would have to update the DNS to point to the new domain.

Is there a way to change certificate for AWS APIGateway custom domain?

Thanks

-Gs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are happy to announce that we just published certificate rotation support for custom domain names. You can use this new feature to update your SSL certificates without incurring downtime to your production API.

Please have a look at our [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html#how-to-rotate-custom-domain-certificate) for more details.

Comment: To expand on this (still valid answer) you want to issue an `update-domain-name` operation, relevant links: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-domain-name.html
+
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/domainname-update/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to update the certificate on a custom domain in API Gateway, at this time. The team is working on providing this functionality, but cannot comment on a specific date for release.

An option, though far from ideal, would be to delete and recreate the domain name with the updated cert. You would incur downtime of 1-2 hours if you went this route.

If you have significant production traffic, need to rotate a cert in the near future, and absolutely cannot afford the downtime I would suggest contacting AWS support as they may be able to manually apply the certificate rotation for you, on a case-by-case basis.

The team will update this post once the certificate rotation functionality has been released.

Comment: Thanks. I hope the functionality would be available soon.